# How is the main shape of Nitinol made?

Tags: material-science, physical-chemistry, metals

I understand that **Nitinol** is a **shape-memory alloy**, such that it "reforms to its original shape" when heated to its transformation temperature. But what I don't understand is, how is the original shape of the Nitinol even made in the first place? And just what happens during production that the Nitinol is able to remember "that" exact shape, like a strip or a spring?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nickel_titanium#Manufacturing_process

Answer (score 0):

The original shape of the nitinol is created at a temperature higher than its transformation temperature, after which it is allowed to cool. This guarantees that the nitinol slab does not "remember" the shapes it was pressed into while still in the factory.